# Select items by data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a summary table created in this way:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

    });
}
```

Result:

```
article_id tag_id
1            3
1            4
2            4
```

How select article_id by tag_id?

My attempts:

```
 $article = Article::select(['id', 'title', 'text', 'image_file'])->where('tags', $request);
```

Comment: You can use `join`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins. Something like this (untested): `Article::select(['id', 'title', 'text', 'image_file'])->join('article_tag', 'article_tag.article_id', '=', 'article.id')->where('article_tag.tag_id', $tagId)`. I'm not up to speed with Eloquent so it might not be 100%.

Comment: Did you set up the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) between articles and tags?

Comment: It work. Thanks.